# Is there a simple way to copy all text in PSD file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a simple way to copy all text in PSD file?

I work with PSD layouts with many separate text layers and they often contain only one word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not without scripting.

I've never used it, but a quick Google search finds [THIS SCRIPT](http://www.bram.us/2008/03/16/ps_bramustextexport-13-automatically-export-all-text-layers-from-photoshop-psd-to-a-text-file/) which claims to be able to export all text layers to a text file.

Comment: this script works for CS3 and CS6. Use this script for above CS6 https://gist.github.com/praveenvijayan/b4c367f4b903a3f9f250

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add some detail to @scott's answer based on my tests:

The following snippets are of the same file, which has a single line of text. My actual task was a colleague's 400mb cs6 file with various layer/folder styles, which omgmog warns us of ahead of time.  Brahmus did the job, and though the extra detail would have been welcome, it was super easy to simplify in Sublime.

I'm using PS CS5.5 Mac.

### PS_BRAMUS.TextConvert

http://www.bram.us/2008/10/30/ps_bramustextconvert-psd2txt-and-txt2psd-for-the-masses/

```
[BEGIN /my text layer ]
my text layer
[END /my text layer ]
```

### omgmog/photoshop-text-export

https://github.com/omgmog/photoshop-text-export

> "This might not work in Adobe Photoshop CS6."

```
*************************************
* START TextExport for test.psd
*************************************


LayerPath: /
LayerName: my text layer


LayerContent:
my text layer


LayerStyles:
* capitalization: uppercase
* color: #55E7A8
* fauxBold:
* fauxItalic:
* font: ProximaNovaSoft-Bold
* size: 17 pt
* tracking:


*************************************
* FINISHED TextExport for test.psd
*************************************
```